# Generics type constraint vs inheritance

Tags: ios, swift, generics, inheritance

Is there a difference between these two function declarations?

```
func doSomething<T: UIViewController>(controller: T) {...}
```

vs.

```
func doSomething(controller: UIViewController) {...}
```

In *Type Constraint Syntax* section of the [Apples Swift programming language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html) book, there's this code sample:

```
func​ ​someFunction​<​T​: ​SomeClass​, ​U​: ​SomeProtocol​>(​someT​: ​T​, ​someU​: ​U​) {
    // function body goes here
}
```

with this description:

> The hypothetical function above has two type parameters. The first type parameter, T, has a type constraint that requires T to be a subclass of SomeClass. ...

So in which cases is it better to use generic function described above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are different, but in the way you are using them, they amount to pretty much exactly the same result.

The difference is that when you call the generic version, the compiler sets `T` statically to be whatever type is passed in as the argument.  When calling methods on that argument, this makes almost no difference – either way the calls on its methods will be dynamically dispatched, and you can't touch any parts of `T` that aren't guaranteed to be available from the constraint.

But suppose you made a change to this method to not just take an argument, but also *return* one, of the same type:

```
// T here will take the type of whatever is going in/out of the function
// be that UIViewController or a subtype of it
func doSomethingGenerically<T: UIViewController>(controller: T) -> T {  
    // some logic that results in a new controller being returned
}

// here the return type is fixed to be UIViewController
func doSomethingViaBaseClass(controller: UIViewController) -> UIViewController {  
    // some logic that results in a new controller being returned
}
```

Now, suppose you had a subclass of `UIViewController` that you were passing in, like so:

```
let subClass: MyUIViewController = ...

let controller1 = doSomethingGenerically(subClass)

let controller2 = doSomethingViaBaseClass(subClass)
```

Here, the type of the variable `controller1` will be `MyUIViewController`, because that is what was passed in to the function so that is what `T` is.  But the type of the variable `controller2` will be `UIViewController` because that is the fixed type that `doSomethingViaBaseClass` returns.

Note, this doesn't mean the object they *reference* will be different - that depends on what the body of the function implements.  It's just the type of the variables *referring* to it that will change.

There are other subtle differences but this is the main one to know about.  In the case of structs, however, there are more differences worth noting.  As it happens I wrote [an article](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/03/26/protocols-and-generics-2/) about them yesterday that might help.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed incorrect method declaration. So generic type restriction can be useful, but in my case, if I don't need to return generic type, it's better to use non-generic version.

Comment: Yes, in the case of reference types and when you aren't returning a `T` or anything like that, the generic version doesn't give benefits so the non-generic is better since it's cleaner.